# How to use \date{\today} without using \maketitle?

Tags: titles, datetime

I am making my own title page. I'd like Latex to display the date automatically using `\date{\today}` but this does not work, since I am not doing `\maketitle`

So instead of setting the date manually myself and worry about updating it, is there a way to make Latex use `\date{\today}` in my own title page?

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}%
%\usepackage{datetime} did not help
\newcommand*{\myTitle}{\begingroup 
\centering 
\vspace*{\baselineskip} 

{\LARGE My Title}% Title
\vspace*{1\baselineskip}    
\scshape % Small caps
My project    
\vspace*{1\baselineskip}
University of Main Street\\[\baselineskip]

\vspace*{5\baselineskip} 

Written by \\[\baselineskip]
{\Large John Due\par}     
\vspace*{1\baselineskip}
\scshape
\date{\today}
%\date{\currenttime}  does not work     
\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty} 
\myTitle
\clearpage

This is my report
\end{document}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I googled and gave up after 15 minutes search.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I get an error when I do that. `Paragraph ended before \date was complete \myTitle`

Comment: Sorry. I meant `\today`, as in my answer.

Comment: I appreciate the use of the name John Due

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Simply use `\today`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}%
%\usepackage{datetime} did not help
\newcommand*{\myTitle}{\begingroup 
\centering 
\vspace*{\baselineskip} 


{\LARGE My Title}% Title
\vspace*{1\baselineskip}

\scshape % Small caps
My prject

\vspace*{1\baselineskip}
University of Main Street\\[\baselineskip]


\vspace*{5\baselineskip} 

Written by \\[\baselineskip]
{\Large John Due\par} 

\vspace*{1\baselineskip}
\today

\endgroup\clearpage}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty} 
\myTitle

This is my report
\end{document}
```

[image]